# How to filter standard picklist based on formula field?

Tags: formula, dependent-picklist

I am trying to filter the standard Type picklist on a standard object based on a field on the connected Account (if it is connected).  Furthermore, this picklist has to be filtered on the initial object creation screen.

I tried creating a Formula Checkbox that is linked to the field on the Account but that Formula field is not available under the "Controlling Field" drop-down.  Also, Type is not available as a Dependent Field, suggesting this overall idea will not work.  Is there a way of doing this without building a VF page?

My backup plan is a validation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, controlling fields can only be picklists or checkboxes, and not formulas, lookups, or other types of values. You'll need to either use Visualforce, a validation rule, or a trigger.

Comment: Thanks for confirming.  You mention the use of a Trigger - would that only be effective for processing after saving much the like Validation Rule?

Comment: Correct. The point of the trigger would be only if the validation rule became so complex that it was impractical to manage. *Customization over coding* should be your mantra, but sometimes you have a situation so out of control that proper coding is the only way to go.